# Which one to use Hset or HMSet in Redis?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am kind of new to Redis. I am just trying to store values in Redis using the HashSet method available using  StackExchange.Redis.StrongName assembly (Lets say I have 4000 items). Is it better to store the 4000 items individually (using HSet ) or shall I pass a dictionary (using HMSet) so it will call only Redis server call is required but a huge amount of data. Which one is better?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

HMSET has been deprecated as of redis 4.0.0 in favor of using HSET with multiple key/value pairs:

https://redis.io/commands/hset

https://redis.io/commands/hmset

Performance will be O(n)

Comment: O(N) where N is the number of field-value pairs

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR A single call is "better" in terms of performance.

Taking into consideration @dizzyf's answer about `HMSET`'s deprecation, the question becomes "should I use a lot of small calls instead of one big one?". Because there is an overhead to process every command, it is usually preferred to "batch" calls together to reduce the price.

Some commands in Redis are varidiac, a.k.a dynamic arity, meaning they can accept one or more values to eliminate multiple calls. That said, overloading a single call with a huge amount of arguments is also not the best practice - that typically leads to massive memory allocations and blocks the server from serving other requests during its processing.

I would approach this by dividing the values to constant-sized "batches" - 100 is a good start, but you can always tune it afterwards - and sending each such "batch" in a single `HSET key field1 value1 ... field100 value1000` call.

Pro tip: if your Redis client supports it, you can use [pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to make everything more responsive ("better"?).